# Execute stored procedure to select data - Mule 3.3.0

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, mule, jtds

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure to `SELECT` data from a SQL Server 2008 database using Mule 3.3.0.

In the Mule docs there is info about doing this with Oracle. I'm not sure if this is possible with SQL Server.

This is my Mule endpoint config

```
<jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="sqlServerConnector" queryKey="selectCoupons" doc:name="Database">
    <jdbc:query key="selectCoupons" value="call sp_get_coupons()"/>
</jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
```

This is the output

```
Root Exception stack trace:
java.sql.SQLException: The executeUpdate method must not return a result set.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:603)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:546)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:506)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

I'm using the jTDS driver. Testing the stored procedure with a JDBC client I get the expected resultSet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Never done anything with that. But wouldn't you use something like "exec sp_....". the "call" looks weird.

Comment: Maybe mule can't get the result of the stored procedure, but it was actually executed. You could try this by creating an own stored procedure which updates some values.

Comment: Already tried that. This is what I get: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No SQL Strategy found for SQL statement: exec sp_get_coupons()

Comment: `call sp_get_coupons()` is the right syntax. I see where the problem comes from (Mule uses `update` instead of `select` which makes jTDS mad) but I'm unsure about the best fix for it. How do you run the call with straight JDBC?

Comment: @DavidDossot with straight JDBC I use `sp_get_coupons` and works fine. I'll try to call a User defined function instead of a Stored procedure to see if it works

Comment: I meant: what code do you use? prepare statement, call, whatever... it's for estimating the difference between what you do that works and what Mule does.

Comment: I execute `sp_get_coupons` directly from [ExecuteQuery](http://executequery.org) database utility. I didn't try to do it programmatically

Answer (score -1):

```css
<db:stored-procedure config-ref="Oracle_Configuration1" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{call apps.create_sales_Order(:p_header_rec_oper,:P_order_number,:P_ordered_date,:P_line_id,:p_flow_Status_code,:P_return_status)}]]></db:parameterized-query>
            <db:in-param name="p_header_rec_oper" value="CREATE"/>
            <db:out-param name="P_order_number" type="INTEGER"/>
            <db:out-param name="P_ordered_date" type="DATE"/>
            <db:out-param name="P_line_id" type="VARCHAR"/>
            <db:out-param name="p_flow_Status_code" type="VARCHAR"/>
            <db:out-param name="P_return_status" type="VARCHAR"/>
            
</db:stored-procedure>

{
• P_return_status: "S",
• P_line_id: "684229",
• p_flow_Status_code: "ENTERED",
• P_ordered_date: "2015-05-22",
• P_order_number: 69393
}
```